# Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement dateutil

Tags: 14.04

I want to install **dateutil** so I run this command:

```
pip install dateutil
```

But I got this message error:

```
Downloading/unpacking dateutil
  Real name of requirement dateutil is dateutil
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement dateutil
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for dateutil
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you thinking of [`python-dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil)? `pip` needs you to be specific so either search [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=dateutil&submit=search) or use `pip search dateutil`.

**Important note**: `python-dateutil` is packaged and part of Ubuntu. It is depended on by a large number of packages (run `apt-cache rdepends python-dateutil` to see). If you install over the top of this with `sudo pip` into your site-packages, **you may break Ubuntu**.

So you could just `sudo apt-get install python-dateutil` but if you need a later version of `python-dateutil`, I *strongly* recommend using Virtualenv to create a local Python environment that you use for your application that the rest of Ubuntu doesn't need to know about. Infinitely safer than overwriting pakcage-installed file.